# Is there an alternative to instanceof when filtering a Java stream by class?

Tags: java, inheritance, collections

I have an unexpected situation in a project in which all types extending one class are packed into a Java collection; but only a specific extension of that class contains an additional method. Let's call it "also()"; and let me be clear that no other extension has it. Right before performing one task on every item in that collection, I need to call also() on every item that implements it.

The easiest way forward is this:

```
stuff.stream().filter(item -> item instanceof SpecificItem)
            .forEach(item -> ((SpecificItem)item).also()));
stuff.stream().forEach(item -> item.method());
```

It works fine, but I'm not comfortable with the "instanceof" in there. That's generally a marker of bad code smell. It is very possible that I will refactor this class just to get rid of it. Before I do something that dramatic, though, I thought I would check with the community and see if someone with more experience with either Streams or Collections had a simpler solution.

As an example (certainly nonexclusive), is it possible to get a view of a collection that filters entries by class?

Comment: If you need to filter on `SpecificItem`, and this is the proper way to specify the predicate, then why are you squeamish about the `instanceof` being there?

Comment: Do the objects in the stream implement some common interface that would let you to discriminate between classes? Some `.getKind()` or `.isSpecific()`?

Comment: @9000 Unfortunately no, and I believe that adding such a thing would clutter it a little further.

Comment: Does `also()` need to be called on all instances before any are called with `method()` or just that particular one?

Comment: @RobertHarvey My concern is that usage of instanceof is generally a sign that I am overlooking something more intrinsic to the language. It is almost never necessary. My belief is that it is also unnecessary here; I'm just not sure how to get around it yet.

Comment: @TristanBurnside Just that particular one, many instances do not have it. They don't inherit it and implement it differently; they literally have no pointer to that method.

Comment: Is there a reason that `SpecificItem`'s implementation doesn't just call `also()` first then?

Comment: If you are using Guava, you can do:

``Iterables.filter(stuff, SpecificItem.class).stream().forEach(SpecificItem::also)``

Comment: @LuísGuilherme `Iterable` doesn't have a `stream()` method, but you can call `forEach()` directly on an `Iterable`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is protected, so I need to write a comment. I had a similiar problem and I solved it like this: `stuff.stream().filter(SpecificItem.class::isInstance).map(SpecificItem.class::cast).forEach(item -> item.method());` First, you only get the Items of the specific sub-class, then you cast each remaining Item to this subclass, then you call the `method()`for each item. There is an instanceof (at least some kind of), but this solution is far better readable

Comment: Not always a code smell! What @LuísGuilherme said but no need to convert to a stream - e.g.: `Iterables.filter(stuff, SpecificItem.class).forEach(i -> i.also());` Guava is nice in that as well as having plugged the gaps before streams, it _still_ plugs many JDK gaps with thoughtfully-designed APIs & gives seasoned advice where streams are to be preferred.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest tossing in a `.map` call to do the cast for you.  Then your later code can use the 'real thing'.

Before:

```
stuff.stream().filter(item -> item instanceof SpecificItem)
            .forEach(item -> ((SpecificItem)item).also()));
```

After:

```
stuff.stream().filter(item -> item instanceof SpecificItem)
            .map(item -> (SpecificItem)item)
            .forEach(specificItem -> specificItem.also()));
```

This isn't perfect, but seems to clean things up a little.

Comment: It is my interest to remove as much casting as I can from the work code, and you're right, map meant for that exactly.

Comment: More functionally: stuff.stream().filter(SpecificItem.class::isIstance).map(SpecificItem.class::cast).forEach(SpecificItem::also);

Answer (score 3):

> I have an unexpected situation in a project in which all types extending one class are packed into a Java collection; but only an extension of that class implements a method. Let's call it "also()". Right before performing one task on every item in that collection, I need to call also() on every item that implements it.

That is obviously a defective design. From what you wrote it is not clear, what it means, that one class does not *implement* the method. If it simply does *nothing*, it wouldn't matter, so I assume there is an unwanted side effect.

> It works fine, but I'm not comfortable with the "instanceof" in there.

Your guts are right. Good object oriented design would work without further knowledge what exactly an object, resp whether it is an instance of a special kind.

> Before I do something that dramatic, though, I thought I would check with the community and see if someone with more experience with either Streams or Collections had a simpler solution.

Refactoring is not dramatic. It improves code quality.

With your given codebase, the simplest solution would be, to make sure, you have two separate collections, one with the parent and one with the child class. But that's not quite clean.

Comment: I've edited my question to be more specific. To clarify further, this is a crack-job for a change needed immediately; an extension of the class has to be taken into account. As to refactoring, let's just say that it's an essential part of being a programmer. However, I'm looking for the least dramatic refactor possible.

Comment: To your question, there is a clear answer: if the filter needs to know, with which instance it has to deal, there is no way around _instance of_ (except some kind of weirdo reflection-magic, which is a more cryptic way of asking _instanceof_). But the time you save now for a _quick and dirty_ solution is spent later on in the product lifecyle double on fixing bugs due to a bad design.

Comment: @MichaelEricOberlin: So if I hear Thomas correctly, your choices appear to be: change the design, or leave it the way it is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey put it this way, it sounds tautologic ;) if he do es not want to refactor,  there is no other option left than going down the current road.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to give specific recommendations without knowing what `SpecificItem` and `also()` actually are, but:

Define `also()` on the superclass of `SpecificItem`. Give it a default implementation which does nothing (give it an empty method body). Individual subclasses can override it if desired. Depending on what `also` actually is, you may need to rename it to something which makes sense for all the classes involved.

Comment: That's quite sensible, and I may end up eventually refactoring to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm not missing anything obvious here (also as suggested by [@Tristan Burnside's comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264106/is-there-an-alternative-to-instanceof-when-filtering-a-java-stream-by-class#comment537287_264106)), but why can't `SpecificItem.method()` call `also()` first?

```
public class SpecificItem extends Item {
    ...
    public void method() {
        also();
        super.method();
    }
}
```

> As an example (certainly nonexclusive), is it possible to get a view of a collection that filters entries by class?

A stream-y way I can think of, at the expense of maybe some performance impact( YMMV), is to `collect()`  via `Collectors.groupingBy()` on the class as the key, then pick what you want from the resulting `Map`. The values are stored as a `List`, so if you were expecting to do such a filtering on a `Set` and you hope to get a filtered `Set` out of it, then you will need an additional step to further put the values into a resulting `Set` as well.

Answer (score 1):

an alternative:

1. make **SpecificItem** implement an interface (say "Filterable")
2. make a new class that extends Stream
3. create a new 'filter' method which accept object that implement your interface
4. override the original stream method and redirect it to your implementation (by casting the **predicate** parameter to your interface)

that way only objects which implement your interface would be able to pass themeselves to your method... no need to use **instanceof**

```
public class MyStream extends Stream
{
    //...

    Stream<Filterable> filter(Predicate<? implements Filterable> predicate)
    {
         return super.filter(predicate);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not the way: to improve bad design by making it worse.

Comment: I have to agree with Thomas Junk here. Step three basically does what I'm already doing; and without again using instanceof, I fail to see how your method would resolve this.

Comment: @MichaelEricOberlin: This is exactly what I was worried about; creating a Rube Goldberg just to satisfy someone's idea of a "best practice."

Answer (score -1):

Here is my approach:

```
stuff.stream().filter(item -> SpecificItem.class.isInstance(item)).map(item  -> SpecificItem.class.cast(item)).forEach(item -> item.also());
stuff.stream().forEach(item -> item.method());
```

No *instanceof*, no explicit casts (actually it is an explicit cast, but masked by a method call). I think this is as good as it can get.

Comment: Isn't this just a less readable version of the original?

Comment: Well, it actually does the same in a typesafe way. It may be simpler depending on the context of the code. I use this for filtering certain types inside a generic list, except for the forEach part.